# How can I mimic an irc server disconnect to test my nodejs irc bot?

Tags: node.js, sockets, events, iptables, irc

I'm using the `net.Socket` module to connect to EFNET and testing my code in order to add a reconnect event to my bot.

What are some ways I can mimic the bot disconnecting? The issue is very 2-3 weeks it disconnects - I have added event handlers in order to understand which happens when it disconnects from IRC:

```
irc = {
      info:{}
    , listeners : []
    , socket : new net.Socket()
}


irc.socket.on('timeout', function() {
    console.log('timeout');
}); 

irc.socket.on('error', function() {
    console.log('error');
}); 

irc.socket.on('end', function() {
    console.log('end??')
    setTimeout(function() {
        //irc.socket.connect(config.server.port, config.server.addr);
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Or if anyone has knowledge on which actual event happens usually with relating to irc bots, I'd appreciate it.

EDIT #1: Maybe I could I do something with `iptables` and filter the port while it's running or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2):

An `IRC` event isn't fired when the bot disconnects, it just closes the connection between the client and server.

You could setup your own IRC server and use the `KLINE` or `GLINE` command (As an IRC administrator) to ban your bot off the server which would force close the connection and mimic a disconnect.

Comment: Ah ok. Would you recommend having some sort of ping/pong connectivity test in order to see if it's still "connected", or what can I do for that?

Comment: The server should sending regular `PING` intervals to the client.  Simply don't reply to them and the server should disconnect you.